# Can the output of an array function be used in an Excel Table?

Tags: excel

I have an array formula that outputs a range of data - roughly 100 rows * 4 columns.

I want to use this output in an Excel Table *without* having to copy it elsewhere.

Is this possible?

When I create a table by going Home -> Format as Table
and then try to enter a formula array into the area it says "Multi-cell array formulas aren't allowed in tables".

Is there another way to achieve it?

Comment: In case of table you do not need array approach. Table rows will fill formulas to all cells in a column automatically.

Comment: As @Harun24hr said, if you're creating a table then the formula will fill down automatically so you can create a formula that returns a single value and it will populate your table.  If you need a formula that returns an array you can reference all of that array with `=A1#` if you array starts in A1.  Or you can use `=INDEX(A1#,,1)` to reference the just the first column of your array.  But for your question - no, multi-cell array formulas aren't allowed in tables.

Comment: @Harun24hr the input for the table is an array outputted from a function